# Celery can not find tasks nor settings with Django 2.1.1

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-2.1

I am trying to do Asynchronous task using Celery and RabbitMQ server. I have installed `Celery` and `RabbitMQ` on my system. Now when I'm running `celery worker -l info`, the celery starts working using default configuration settings ignoring my settings and it shows no registered tasks. I am assuming there is something wrong because of my project structure. But its not possible to change it now. Can anyone help me figure out what's the problem here?

*Tasks are not found and it starts with default settings ignoring my username and password and vhost mentioned in settings file.*
[image: Tasks are not found and it starts with default settings ignoring my username and password and vhost mentioned in settings file.]

**Project Directory:**

```
|--engine
|  |--app
|  |   |--user
|  |   |--program
|  |   |  |--__init__.py
|  |   |  |--admin.py
|  |   |  |--apps.py
|  |   |  |--models.py
|  |   |  |--tasks.py
|  |   |  |--urls.py
|  |   |  |--views.py
|  |   |--course
|  |--config
|  |   |--settings
|  |   |  |--__init.py
|  |   |  |--default.py
|  |   |  |--development.py
|  |   |  |--production.py
|  |   |--__init__.py
|  |   |--celery.py
|  |   |--middleware.py
|  |   |--urls.py
|  |   |--wsgi.py
|  |--.env
|  |--manage.py
|  |--requirements.txt
```

**engine/config/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.default')

app = Celery('config')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**engine/config/__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**engine/app/program/tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task()
def add(number1, number2):
    print(number1 + number2)
```

**engine/config/settings/default.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',

    'app.program',
    'app.course',
    'app.user',
]

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://uname:pass@localhost:5672/vhost/'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: where are you calling add.delay(..) function?

Comment: That's in my app/programs/views.py file. Its actually more of a configuration problem. Because my tasks should be available in [tasks] when I run `celery worker` which is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is with Windows. As mention on their website -

```
Does Celery support Windows?
Answer: No.

Since Celery 4.x, Windows is no longer supported due to lack of resources.

But it may still work and we are happy to accept patches.
```

**resources: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#windows**

Answer (score 2):

I see three problems with your configuration so far:

1. In settings file, you should specify the broker url by name BROKER_URL and not by CELERY_BROKER_URL.
2. The decorator specified in tasks.py should be @shared_task instead of @shared_task()
3. Specify the paths where celery should look for tasks. In celery.py file, update

   ```
   app.autodiscover_tasks()
   ```

   with

   ```
   app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   ```

Comment: Where should I import the settings from? is it `from django.conf import settings` ?

Comment: according to the documentation `namespace="CELERY" means all celery-related configuration keys should have a "CELERY_" prefix` Can you please define that? I have gone through with your settings and still the same result.